# Is React.js a library or a framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, frameworks

Hello sometimes I hear the word library for react js,  sometimes it's called a framework.
So just wondering, what is more accurate?

Answer (score 1):

According to their website it's a Library.
https://reactjs.org/

[image]